# Помогите не работает height:auto

Tags: css

Я сделал body с использованием

```
body
{
    margin: auto;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height:auto ;
    width:970px;
    background-color:#FFF;  
}
```

но сайт не увеличивается а он все также 100%, когда опускаешь просто пустота не работает авто. Я пытался исправить но все бессмысленно!

Comment: я использую код добавления информации из mysql через циклы  как это решить

Answer (score 2):

Я, конечно, понимаю, что отвечать ссылкой не комильфо, но тут очень хорошо описан Ваш случай, прямо в начале: http://habrahabr.ru/post/189252/

Comment: Старайтесь писать ответ содержательным, а ссылку приводить как дополнение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать контейнер. И уже в нем задавать высоту. Для body высоту указывать бесполезно.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```